# Making Variables Global in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, global

Need to make $courseInfo and $row global so that they can be used for printing the row details in the header DIV.

Don't have a clue how to do this. Any help would be great.

```
<?php 


// Get Course ID From Link
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ID']);

// Check the Course ID exists
$courseCheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE CourseID = '".$ID."'");

if (mysql_num_rows($courseCheck) == 1) {

    $checkMember = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CourseMembers WHERE CourseID = '".$ID."' AND UserID = '".$_SESSION['UserID']."'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($checkMember) == 1) {

        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
            <!-- Style Sheets -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/reset.css" type="text/css" media=screen />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media=screen />
        </head>
        <body>

        <?php
        if ($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == 1){ 

            $courseInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE CourseID = '".$ID."'");
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($courseInfo);

        ?>

            <div id="container">
                <div id="side">
                    <?php include("lib/sidebar.php"); ?>
                </div>
                <div id="main">
                    <div id="mainbox">
                        <div id="header"><b><?php echo $row['CourseName']; ?></b></div>
                        <p>Hello world, this is a test.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php
            } 
        else { 
            echo "Not logged in.";
        }

    }

    else {
        echo "You are not a member of this Course";
    }

}

else {
    echo "No Course Found";
}

?>
</body>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: If $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == 1 fails, them $courseInfo and $row will never be created. BTW, you're not supposed to mix PHP and HTML like that. PHP only allows this for historical reasons. No one does that anymore. You need to learn how to properly structure a PHP program first. Read up on cake PHP and the zend framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they're already global. ["PHP does not have a block-level scope."](http://www.daaq.net/old/php/index.php?page=php+variables&parent=php+basics)

Comment: They can't be surely because it isn't printing the details.

Comment: @ritch What do you mean by 'the same scope'? Where did you move it to get it to work?

Comment: below the include of the lib/sidebar.php

Comment: @ritch Maybe `sidebar.php` is introducing *other* global variables that are messing with the current page. For example, maybe it has a variable named `$row` that is overwriting your current `$row`.

Answer (score 1):

You could store them in session variables, similarly to your `$_SESSION['LoggedIn']`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use php variable $GLOBALS for making your variables visible in all scopes but I would not recommend it for this kind of task. Also, beware - $GLOBALS contains superglobals like $_POST and $_GET, you should keep that in mind, when ie. iterating over it. Furthermore - when you can access $_GET and $_POST in functions, that have smaller scope you still have to use $GLOBALS to access custom ones.

Example for this kind behaviour:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

$GLOBALS['_customVar'] = 'foobar';
$GLOBALS['_GET']['id'] = 'myId';

    function myFnc() {
    echo $_customVar;
    }

    function myFnc2() {
    echo $_GET['id'];
    }

myFnc();
myFnc2();

?>
```